# Many-To-Many relationship not persisted using GORM and Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, many-to-many, grails-orm

Using GORM with Grails 3.3.6 a many-to-many relationship is not persisted.

I followed examples at http://gorm.grails.org/6.1.x/hibernate/manual/#gormAssociation (paragraph 5.1.3). Book and Author objects are persisted, but book_authors table is empty.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a new app:

```
grails create-app helloworld
cd helloworld
grails create-controller hello
grails create-domain-class Book
grails create-domain-class Author
```

Edit`helloworld\grails-app\domain\helloworld\Book.groovy`

```
package helloworld

class Book {
    static belongsTo = Author
    static hasMany = [authors:Author]
    String title
}
```

Edit `helloworld\grails-app\domain\helloworld\Author.groovy`

```
package helloworld

class Author {
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
    String name
}
```

Edit `helloworld\grails-app\controllers\helloworld`

```
package helloworld

class HelloController {

    def index() { 
        
        new Author(name:"Stephen King")
        .addToBooks(new Book(title:"The Stand"))
        .addToBooks(new Book(title:"The Shining"))
        .save()
    
    }
}
```

Then `grails run-app` and go to http://localhost:8080/hello. Open http://localhost:8080/dbconsole with URL `jdbc:h2:mem:devDb` to see the resulting database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to annotate the controller action with `@Transactional` to have the changes persisted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue in how the GORM works, check the next [link](https://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany)

```
package mx.jresendiz27.gorm.test

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        //  https://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany
        // works
        new Author(name:"Stephen King")
        .addToBooks(new Book(title:"The Stand"))
        .addToBooks(new Book(title:"The Shining"))
        .save()
        // does not work, should use save in each author
        new Book(title:"Groovy in Action")
        .addToAuthors(new Author(name:"Dierk Koenig").save())
        .addToAuthors(new Author(name:"Guillaume Laforge").save())
        .save(flush:true, failOnError: true)
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Also I recommend you using different domains for handling the many-to-many relationships, because [it's harmful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nofscHeEuU) to use the relationships in the GORM